# Guardar suma cada 6 números c++

Tags: c++

Quiero sumar los primeros 6 valores, y se vayan guardando en un arreglo a[], de ahí, que los siguientes 6 valores vuelvan a sumar y se guarde en la posición a[++], esto hasta llegar al limite es decir.

Si son 24 números, debería haber a[0=6], a[1=6],a[2=6], asi hasta llegar hasta el arreglo numero 4. Ya que 24 entre 6 es 4. Nada mas. (Lo de random de 1 hasta 1, es para que siempre me arroje un numero random y siempre será 1, lo hice porque quería saber si seis veces el numero 1 se sumaban y se guardaban en el arreglo [0] por ejemplo, esto lo cambiaría después solo es para comprobar si los números 1 se estaban sumando, simple comprovación) Saludos amigos de la comunidad.

a .- posición 1: 6

a.- posición 2: 6

a.- posición 3: 6

a.- posición 4: 6

esto resolveria el problema (porque se verifica que si se están sumando los seis 1) y podría ahora si poner random del 1 al 10, aqui mi ejemplo de código que me da otros valores. Pido ayuda

```
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int v = 0;
    int sum;
    int x = 6;
    int a[100];
    for (int i = 0; i< 6; i++) {
        v = rand() % 1 + 1;
        cout << v;
        sum += v;
        if(i%6==0){
            a[i]=sum;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout << sum;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<a[0];




        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Que es la posicion `a[++]`? Creeme que por mas veces que he leido lo que colocaste no he logrado entender lo que quieres. Esto es lo que entendi: Quieres los primeros 6 sumados en `a[0]`, los siguientes 6 en `a[1]`, y asi hasta el final? Si no es eso, puedes clarificar un poco lo que quieres.

Comment: a[++] es que a[0] hasta a[n] y si lo que dices es lo que quiero hacer @Pablochaches

Comment: *"a[++] es que a[0] hasta a[n]"*, seria mejor que colocaras el significado literal, en lugar de la abreviación. Eso nos ayudara a los mensos a enteder mas rapido lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) de la cabecera [`<numeric>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numeric), esta función suma los valores desde el primer parámetro hasta llegar al segundo parámetro y toma como valor inicial el tercer parámetro. Por lo tanto, si haces esto:

```
int valores[]{  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, };

for (int indice = 0; indice != 4; ++indice)
    valores[indice] = std::accumulate(valores + (indice * 6), valores + ((indice + 1) * 6), 0);
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                          \___ 0, 6, 12, 18               \___ 6, 12, 18, 24
```

Obtendrás el resultado que buscas. Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY/BisIwEIbPyVP868LabBUUxENbfYi9Lh5CmpVAmkgy6UV89m6jLbuehTBk/pn55h91uayVle48DO/GKZtajcb4SEHL7sj/NJc6HYw6cm4coZPGFYJfOctZL60POn6frmy7wvPjjL0i4lZzzn58QJE3GdcapXHApp7/bwfsapTlIxUjZbbzUE5jd6S2qqRSqUtWki6mDpSZeqd8Yi9W@KfPhRJbMVU3Inu5s5RPhKbB4kvHZEm2vsKinowq7yJBJvL46FHN1GztabjPYYllpgZNKbjxLH4bhl8)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

El problema, segun lo que entiendo, al final radica en como separarlos en grupos de 6. La solución la podemos encontrar siguiendo un patrón que explico en el codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

constexpr int limite = 24; // Según el ejemplo que colocaste
constexpr int valores_por_posicion = 6;

// No hace falta que le des 100 espacios a `a`, si el tamaño ya lo conoces en
// tiempo de compilacion. 
constexpr int a_size = limite / valores_por_posicion;

int main(void) {
    srand(time(nullptr)); // Usar rand tiene aleatoriedad limitada, hechale un
                          // vistaso a <random>

    int a[a_size] = {0};  // Seria mejor que le heches un vistaso a std::vector
                          // o std::array

    for (int i = 0; i < limite; i++) {
        // 0 a 5 dividido 6 y aproximado al entero menor es 0
        // 6 a 11 dividido 6 y aproximado al entero menor es 1
        // Y el patron sigue, entonces puedes calcular la posicion asi:
        const int posicion = i / valores_por_posicion;
        const int v = (std::rand() % 1) + 1;
        a[posicion] += v;
    }

    std::cout << "Las sumas son: " << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        std::cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << a[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No entendí varias cosas, soy nuevo, pero si da así que te pongo palomita, me podrías explicar para que es el constexprt? y como es que funciona el arreglo en esta solución? te lo agradecería me gusta aprender y disculpa las molestias

Comment: `constexpr` son constantes que se calculan cuando compilas tu programa. Es bueno para tener constantes, en lugar de tener un montón de números mágicos a lo largo del código.  El arreglo hace lo que decías en el problema (Eso o no entendí tu pregunta).  Cualquier otra duda que tengas nos cuentas, ya sea aqui en los comentarios o en una pregunta nueva. Mucha suerte.

Comment: que significa const int v = (std::rand() % 1) + 1; me refiero porque no simplemente es Rand()% 1 + 1; ? que tiene de diferencia al que puse yo

Comment: `std::` significa que estoy accediendo a algo dentro del espacio de nombres `std`. Lo coloque así porque no tengo hasta arriba el `using namespace std;`. Lo siento si fue confuso para ti, lo hice por costumbre.

Comment: ¿Para qué usas `std::floor`? La expresión sobre la que lo usas es entera ¡es absurdo!

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Cuando lo estaba escribiendo lo hize para que aproxime al entero menor, no lo pense mucho. Gracias por el comentario, ahorita lo quito.

Comment: @Pablochaches las divisiones entre enteros no tienen decimales y siempre aproximan al entero menor.

Comment: Me refiero al rand()%1)+1), porque no simplemente rand()% 1 +1, que diferencia hay entre esos? @Pablochaches

Comment: @Xetine Ahh, ya te entendi. Es porque soy menso, y si tengo los parentesis entiendo mas rapido el orden en el que se haran las cosas, si lo pones o no en realidad no importa.